# Will adding 100 meta keywords to the same page hurt or help SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, meta-tags, meta-keywords

Is it possible to add several keywords to the same page? Will this penalize my page by Google?

Example:

[image: meta-keywords elements with multiple keywords]

What is the implication in adding many keywords? I am expecting I get traffic from all keywords, if it is 100 or 1000000.

Also I would like to know, `meta`-`name` should be `keyword` or anything I can put there like `<meta name="anything"`?

Comment: See [google's list of meta tags it uses](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812).

Answer (score 24):

Since 2009 it is Google's official statement that they don't use the meta keywords tag for ranking purposes: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

They in fact even that they sometimes use it as a spam signal, especially for webmasters that enter a great number of keywords in it.

In terms of inserting keywords in a meta tag, you need a `<meta name="keywords">` setup.

Long story short: don't use `<meta name="keywords">`.

Comment: then where should i put the keywords?

Comment: On the webpage itself. I suggest you to have a look at https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo

Comment: @SmartestVEGA keywords should naturally appear within the 'written content' found on the page. Not a list of jumbo list of keywords either on the page or off-the page.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: Nowhere. You just asking this question has cost you more time than usefull tweaks. Focus on good content. Thats about it.

Comment: I completely agree with this post. Focus on quality content and the rest will handle itself

Comment: @SmartestVEGA, "keyword stuffing" is generally quite counterproductive.

Comment: Keyword stuffing had been used in the past to obtain top search engine rankings and visibility for particular phrases. This method is outdated and adds no value to rankings today. In particular, Google no longer gives good rankings to pages employing this technique.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_stuffing

Answer (score 1):

Since keywords are not used anymore for referencing.
Just put the best words at the best places (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc.. tags)

Just make sure to priorities the words.

Comment: heading tags such as h1, h2, and h3 don't even have SEO relevance anymore.  These days Googlebot renders pages.   It now pays attention to how big, bold, and prominent the text on the page ends up being after being styled.   Googlebot doesn't seem to pay much attention at all to the tags anymore.

Comment: Using headers help to priorities information and then put the correct CSS on those tags to automatically reference the better words without having to pay attention to some formating.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add several keywords to the same page?

Yes but It doesn't seem practical.

> Will this penalize my page by Google?

Possibly (see below)

> What is the implication in adding many keywords? I am expecting I get traffic from all keywords, if it is 100 or 1000000. Also I would like to know, meta-name should be keyword or...

It's actually a wonderful way to make your server slow.

The reason is because in your image example, if you start adding a whole bunch of keywords in your meta tags then its more data the browser must process before users see content. This will hurt mobile users with poor data connections (and no wifi) who are trying to connect to your website, and if your site is by chance extremely popular, its possible that hundreds of  mobile users with poor connections are hitting refresh frequently because they think the page isn't working when the middle of the meta tag in the page is being downloaded to all devices at once from the same server. While upgrading the server is an option, your better option is to simply cut back on the code (including unnecessary meta tags) and show more content.

Take a look:

http://tools.seochat.com/tools/code-to-text-ratio/
http://smallseotools.com/code-to-text-ratio-checker/

These are URLs to services that can assess the amount of code to text on your site. It will tell you how much text of an entire page the user can see and how much is code. Try to make the percentage it reports to you high to get better ranked in search engines.

As others mentioned, take those keywords out of the tag and blend them into your actual content that people can see, but make sure the keywords become complete natural paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't use the keywords meta tag in web ranking for this reason. If you use many keywords it won't be helpful for SEO ranking. But it's not good idea from (September 2009), If you won't use it will be better for your site.

Search Engines judged pages only on the content of web pages & off-page SEO.

It's possible that Google could use this information in the future, but it's unlikely. Google has ignored the keywords meta tag for years and currently Google see no need to change that policy. [Read more](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) for details